# Editing a .CSV file through shell automation script

Tags: linux, shell, svn, error-handling

I'm getting an error when trying to execute the script below around the done statement. The point of the code is to have the while statement execute for the duration of files listed in the filenames that log in order to grab the revision number for each file location in my branches folder.

```
filea=/home/filenames.log
fileb=/home/actions.log
filec=/home/revisions.log
filed=/home/final.log


count=1
while read Path do
Status=`sed -n "$count"p $fileb`
Revision=`svn info ${WORKSPACE}/$Path | grep "Revision" | awk '{print $2}'`
if `echo $Path | grep "UpgradeScript"` then
Results="Reverted - ROkere"
Details="Reverted per process"
else if `echo $Path | grep "tsu_includes/shell_scripts"` then
Results="Reverted - ROkere"
Details="Reverted per process"
else
Results="Verified - ROkere"
Details=""
fi
echo "$Path,$Status,$Revision,$Results,$Details" > $filed
count=`expr $count + 1`
done < $filea
```

Answer (score 0):

- need a semicolon or newline before `do` and `then`.
- Change `else if` to `elif`
- change

  ```
  if `echo $Path | grep "UpgradeScript"` then
  ```

  to (removing backticks, using "here-string", and `-q` option for grep)

  ```
  if grep -q "UpgradeScript" <<< "$Path"; then
  ```
- "filed" will only ever contain just one line. I assume you want to append `>>` instead of overwrite `>`

---

Actually, a quick rewrite. You're reading corresponding lines from 2 files. Faster to do that completely within the shell instead of invoking `sed` once for each line in the file.

```
#!/bin/bash
filea=/home/filenames.log
fileb=/home/actions.log
filec=/home/revisions.log    # not used?
filed=/home/final.log

exec 3<"$filea"    # open $filea on fd 3
exec 4<"$fileb"    # open $fileb on fd 4

while read -u3 Path && read -u4 Status; do
    Revision=$(svn info "$WORKSPACE/$Path" | awk '/Revision/ {print $2}')
    if [[ "$Path" == *"UpgradeScript"* ]]; then
        Results="Reverted - ROkere"
        Details="Reverted per process"
    elif [[ "$Path" == *"tsu_includes/shell_scripts"* ]]; then
        Results="Reverted - ROkere"
        Details="Reverted per process"
    else
        Results="Verified - ROkere"
        Details=""
    fi
    echo "$Path,$Status,$Revision,$Results,$Details"
done > "$filed"

exec 3<&-   # close fd 3
exec 4<&-   # close fd 4
```